# Problem running compiled Python script

Tags: python

So I have compiled a python script with py2exe according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158369/can-i-somehow-compile-a-python-script-to-work-on-pc-without-python-installed). There were no errors during compilation, everything went fine.

When I run the script from a cmd like this:

```
C:\Users\Richard\Dist\backprop3.exe 60
```

This is the output I get:

```
C:\Users\Richard>C:\Users\Richard\Dist\backprop3.exe 60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backprop3.py", line 209, in <module>
  File "backprop3.py", line 175, in demo
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined

C:\Users\Richard>
```

Which is referring to this line:

```
image = Image.open( os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )+"/backprop-input.bmp" )
```

That line just loads an image from a current directory. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__file__` will not work within py2exe. This is because the module is inside the .exe and thus there is nothing to set `__file__` to which will give you the python file.

See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI for techniques of dealing with this.