# How to run python converted .exe file in other system

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my system Python 3.6 is installed and I have converted my .py file to .exe in my system and the .exe is working fine. But the same .exe file is not working in other systems where Python is not installed.

Please let me know the procedure to run the .exe file without installing Python.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the following information: 1. how did you convert the .py to .exe? 2. what happens when you run it on other systems?

Comment: Have you tried to install python in that computer?

Comment: 1. Using cx_freeze i have converted .py to .exe file
2. No Error is coming
3. No Python is not installed in other system, My question is can I run .py converted .exe file in other system where Python is not installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I somehow "compile" a python script to work on PC without Python installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158369/can-i-somehow-compile-a-python-script-to-work-on-pc-without-python-installed)